# How to do device specific authentication for a web application?

Tags: node.js, authentication, ipad

I'm creating a web application using node and expressjs. I want to be able to be able to perform authentication on the device level and have it be persistent. The way the authentication is currently being done is having deviceId parameter in the browser URL which works and is persistent however is a security concern as a user can easily copy that URL and put it onto another device and gain access to the application. Without requiring authentication to be done via the url or having the user input a username or password what is the best way I can get a unique device id that can be gained through the browser. This application will be used for iPads for context and the webapp is supposed to only be able to be used via work devices.

Comment: Ideally I want to be able to store in a database the list of authenticated device id's and when a device attempts to connect to the web application I can check if it authorized against this list

Comment: You can use `user-agent`  present in the header of the incoming request.